# Issue with Redis or server configuration

Tags: redis

We have 3 dedicated servers from Hetzner and experience the same issue that is described here: http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=500

We have built an advertisement network that delivers about 200k ad impressions per day, and in some days when we have more traffic than usual, then we start getting errors and lose impressions.

Web server and Redis are running on separate servers. We have tried using 2 different redis connectors (phpredis extension and predis library), but still experience the same issue - "connection timed out" errors from time to time.

We've tried increasing various limits in redis.conf without any luck.

Both servers have CPU power and memory to spare.

Maybe anyone has some new ideas, how to solve this?

Comment: So are you running 2.2?  Also have you posted this on the google list or filed a bug on github?

Comment: No, we are running the latest stable version. Have not posted on google list, or filled a bug - it might be a problem with our configuration as well.

Comment: What's the output from the INFO command shortly before/after you get the timeouts. That'd be helpful.